# Can I connect fast & slow ethernet switches to partition network bandwidth?

Tags: ethernet, bandwidth, switch

Let's say I need to provide decent internet access to 20+ computers by way of a single gigabit ethernet port. One computer in particular must have a [bigger tube](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/series-of-tubes). Dozens of other devices are already using local WiFi channels, so I'm sticking to wired.

My idea is to start with an 8-port gigabit switch in the middle. The VIP computer gets a direct connection to that. Then I plug six 100-megabit switches into the remaining ports, and spread the other computers among those.

Will this layout accomplish the "poor man's QoS" that I'm seeking? If not, why not, and what should I do instead?

Comment: That would be a poor choice because (among other problems) if a few of the machines on the 100Mbps switches start talking to each other, other machines on those switches will needlessly have crappy Internet access.

Comment: Another reason it's a poor choice is this: If your Internet access is less than 100Mbps, the other machines can still clog out the VIP computer's Internet access. If your internet access is more than 100Mbps, you've limited the non-VIP machines to 100Mbps even when the VIP computer has no need for bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Followup: The network setup I describe in the question worked exactly as desired. Caveats:

1. Test the wired port's actual bandwidth to the local backbone and to the internet, and make sure it's greater than the combined bandwidth of the secondary switches, so that the VIP computer cannot be choked out.
2. As David commented, if some of the secondary PCs engage in high-bandwidth usage (such as local file transfers) others in their group might experience congestion.
3. Also as David said, this setup may result in slower-than-necessary speeds for secondary PCs, compared to an actively-managed solution.

In my case the secondary PCs were doing light web browsing and receiving streams of known bandwidth (lower than the available total); everyone had enough for their needs.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  What landed the answer in the review queue, and TomEus's comment, is the brevity.  Technically, it answers the question, but it would be much more useful to others if you could expand it and elaborate on the solution and what you learned.  You also might want to accept your own answer, which will clarify that it's you closing the loop and that the question has been answered.